Flutter Apple Carplay variable not reactive
I'm developing a radio app using the flutter_carplay package. The app updates the currently playing track and the next track every 10 seconds via a network request.
Here's a summary of the issue I'm facing:
Background: My app fetches the current and next track information every 10 seconds and is supposed to update the CarPlay interface accordingly.
Problem: Despite updating the track information and attempting to refresh the UI, the CarPlay interface does not reflect these updates. The UI remains as it was when it was first loaded.
Steps Taken:
I tried reloading the rootTemplate to refresh the UI, but this did not resolve the issue.
I ensured that the data is being fetched and updated correctly in the backend.
Questions:
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with flutter_carplay?
Are there specific methods or approaches recommended for updating the CarPlay interface dynamically?
Are there any known issues or limitations with flutter_carplay related to UI updates?
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:myproject/metadata.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter_carplay/flutter_carplay.dart';

class CarPlayManager {
  late Metadata _meta;
  final _assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer.newPlayer();
  String _currentArtist = 'En direct';
  String _currentTitle = 'En direct';
  Map<String, dynamic> _nextTrack = {};
  var isPlayingVal = false;

  Future<void> _fetchMetadata() async {
    final metadata = await _meta.fetchMetadata();
    _currentTitle = metadata.title;
    _currentArtist = metadata.artist;
    _updateCarPlayUI();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchNextTrack() async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https:/mynextrack.example'),
    );
    _nextTrack = json.decode(response.body);
  }

  void initializeCarPlay() async {
    _fetchMetadata();
    _fetchNextTrack();
    late Timer _timer;
    _meta = Metadata(assetsAudioPlayer: _assetsAudioPlayer);

    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 20), (timer) {
      _fetchMetadata();
      _fetchNextTrack();
      _updateCarPlayUI();
    });

    await _assetsAudioPlayer.open(
      Audio.liveStream(
        "https://mystream.example",
        metas: Metas(
          id: _currentArtist,
          title: _currentTitle,
          artist: _currentArtist,
          image: const MetasImage.asset('assets/logo.jpeg'),
        ),
      ),
      autoStart: false,
      showNotification: true,
    );
  }

  void _updateCarPlayUI() {
    FlutterCarplay.setRootTemplate(
      rootTemplate: getTemplate(),
    );
  }

  getTemplate() {
    return CPListTemplate(
      sections: [
        CPListSection(
          items: [
            CPListItem(
              text: _currentTitle,
              detailText: _currentArtist,
              isPlaying: true,
              image: 'assets/logo-no-shadow.png',
              onPress: (complete, self) {
                isPlayingVal = !isPlayingVal;
                print('isPlaying: $isPlayingVal');
                if (isPlayingVal) self.setDetailText("Chargement en cours...");
                _assetsAudioPlayer.playOrPause();

                Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                  self.setDetailText(_currentArtist);
                  complete();
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
          header: "En cours",
        ),
        CPListSection(
          items: [
            CPListItem(
              text: _nextTrack['title'] ?? 'Radio name',
              detailText: _nextTrack['artist'] ?? 'Live',
              image: 'assets/logo-no-shadow.png',
            ),
          ],
          header: "À suivre (dans ${_nextTrack['start_in'] ?? 'N/A'})",
        ),
      ],
      title: "Radio name",
      showsTabBadge: false,
      systemIcon: "house.fill",
    );
  }
}


